# Executing Parsed function calls in Haskell

Tags: haskell, call, interpreter

First i want to say I'm a newbie in Haskell. Here's my problem:
For a school project I need to be able to parse and interprate and execute a fucntion call. This call needs to be able to execute a function already defined in haskell.
Parsing the call works, but i have no idea how to execute the function because the amount of arguments and type is unkown.

Here is how i represent my data

```
type Name = String
type Cond = Expr
data Expr
  = Num Int  
  | Boolean Bool
  | BinOp Op Expr Expr
  | Var Name 
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
data Stmnt 
  = Call Name [Expr]
  | If Cond [Stmnt] [Stmnt]
  | While Cond [Stmnt]
  | VarDef Name Expr
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
```

This is a part of my interpeter. And it is with the implementation of **funcall** that I need help.

```
data Value = FineInt Int 
           | FineBool Bool
           | FineFun ([Value] -> Value)
-- The enviroment keeps track of variables in the program          
type Env = [(Name,Value)]
-- A state that takes an enviroment
type StEnv = State Env

evalstm :: Stmnt -> StEnv ()
evalstm (Call name exprs)  = funcall name exprs

-- funcall name exprs = ?
```

Comment: If you know all possible values for name, you can use a function that manually maps "foo" to foo, "bar" to bar, etc.. If you are to execute arbitrary Haskell code, try [mueval](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mueval).

Comment: I think i'll do it manually for the functions I need, I dont need that many functions (maybe max 10) and I dont think we are allowed to use packages like mueval for this project. Thanks for the help.